# Link 2 annotations together in a window of up to 10 words using Ruta

Tags: nlp, text-mining, uima, ruta

is there a way to link 2 annotations that are within a windows of 10 words, together in a new one?

The following doesn't work:

`Entity W{1,10} Entity{->CREATE(Entity)};`

Thanks and all the best
Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the offsets of a newly created annotation by putting the action at a composed rule element:

```
(Entity W[1,10]{-PARTOF(Entity)} Entity){-> Entity};
```

Please mind the condition at the rule element with the quantifier. The quantifier is greedy and will consume the ANYs in the Entity, whereby the rule won't match as expected or not at all.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*